# codeigniter navigate on click

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

This is probably simple, but still worth asking because I just can't figure it out. I have an index.php view which is loaded from controller via the main function call. Now when am on that site there are links to other views. How do I customize the href of those links? Example one of the is to list all items (and there is a function in controller responsible for that and a view where they are loaded) but how can I invoke that when I click on link "List All"?

Thanks,

Comment: You should read a starting tutorial for the framework. Such things (default routing etc) are explained there.

Comment: I've read the tutorials and went through most of the pages in User Guide. That's how I learned creating models, controllers, helpers, etc. Just not sure how this simple thing would be done

Comment: The default is "/index.php/controller/action/" where "controller" is the name of the controller you want to address and "action" the method (action) you want to invoke in that controller.

Comment: Thanks am going to try it. You may want to put this as answer so if it works for me, then I am going to mark it as answer to help others searching for similar problems.

Comment: And yes that is exactly what I was looking for @Styxxy so please write it as answer :)

Comment: I added it as answer with an extra link to the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default routing in CodeIgniter is `/index.php/controller/action/` where `controller` is the name of the controller you want to address and `action` the method (action) you want to invoke on that controller.

More information about routing in CI can be found here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html .